# In the book Pet Semetary, why does Jud Crandall seem younger than his age?

Tags: stephen-king, pet-sematary

I finished the book recently, and I keep thinking about how Jud was repeatedly described as seeming younger and more spry than his age (83) would imply. It's never explained, but it seems like it has to be important since it was brought up so much. When I read at the end of the book how Louis's hair turned white after what was presumably a brush with some kind of curse (maybe it happened when he killed Gage), it got me thinking--does Jud have white hair because he too brought back and/or killed a daemon? Is he actually younger than 83, and lying about his age to avoid telling the story of what he did? And if that's not the explanation, what does this all mean??

Comment: This reminds me that I once read a story where there was an 82-year-old woman and she was described as being very feeble and decrepit, the way you imagine Jud Crandall should be at the age of 83.  And when I read that I thought about the fact that both of my grandmothers were then at least 82 and were quite active and vigorous. Old people vary a lot in how old they look and how spry they are at the same age.

Answer (score 4):

Going strictly by the book there is no reason to suspect he is lying about his age, IIRC he makes reference to things that occurred during WWII.  Old does not automatically mean infirm.

That being said it is possible his proximity to the Semetery increased his vitality as some form of bleed over from whatever actually powers the place but theres really nothing in the book that would back this up.